# angular material virtual scroll not showing selected value from second page

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I am using angular material library virtual scroll widget 'cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport' and am able to load data in paginated basis on the scroll of it.
But here am facing a problem, how I can show the selected value user saves last time? .Is there any way if the selected item is from second page or nth page, then it loads that page and shows up as select in initial view?

Right now, am doing a hack to create those selected options and appending them to the select box in beginning, so I can show them selected.